# FPDF in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to generate pdf file using laravel 5.2. I have successfully installed the fpdf to my laravel because it can generate a simple pdf. The code is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

use Fpdf;

class ReportHelper{
    public static $elementPerPage = 10;

    public static function generatePDF()
    {
        Fpdf::AddPage();
        Fpdf::SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        Fpdf::Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
        Fpdf::Output();
        exit;
}
}

?>
```

Then I'm following the example from http://www.fpdf.org/ in tutorial 2. If we want to make a new header or footer we need to code like this :

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

So, I created a new class inside of my reportHelper file {class is below ReportHelper} like this :

```
class PDF extends Fpdf
{
     //Header
    function Header()
    {
        //Logo
        $this->Image('mangekyo2.JPG',18,6,25,20,'JPG'); //posisi (x,y), image size
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(70); //title position
        // Title
        $this->Cell(60,10,'Hisoka PDF Title',1,0,'C');//box size
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }


    // Page footer
    function Footer()
    {
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}
```

And then in generatePDF method {inside of ReportHelper class}, I changed the code become like this :

```
class ReportHelper{
    public static $elementPerPage = 10;

    public static function generatePDF()
    {

        // Fpdf::AddPage();
        // Fpdf::SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        // Fpdf::Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
        // Fpdf::Output();
        // exit;

        //Instanciation of inherited class
        $pdf = new PDF();
        $pdf->AliasNbPages();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
        for($i=1;$i<=60;$i++){
            $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
            if($i == 10 || $i== 20 || $i == 30) {
                $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Hisokaline... '.$i,0,1);
                $pdf->Cell(0,10,'X : '.$pdf->GetX().', Y : '.$pdf->GetY(),0,1);
                $pdf->Image('mangekyo2.JPG',48,$pdf->GetY(),25,20,'JPG');

            }
        }
        $pdf->Output();
}
}
```

When I browse/run this page, it gives an error

```
Call to undefined method App\Helpers\PDF::AliasNbPages()
```

I know that AliasNbPages() is a method from Fpdf, but why it can't be recognized ? It's not just AliasNbPages(), but AddPages and SetFont are undefined too, Is there a way for calling this method in laravel ...??
I have tried

```
public static function generatePDF()
    {
        Fpdf::Header()
        {
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
            // Move to the right
            $this->Cell(70); //title position
            // Title
            $this->Cell(60,10,'Hisoka PDF Title',1,0,'C');//box size
            // Line break
            $this->Ln(20);
        };
}
```

It doesn't work too...

Answer (score 2):

**First, install the library Anouar FPDF with this Composer command**

`composer require anouar/fpdf`

**Configuration**

**Then open file /config/app.php, add the following line :**

```
providers' => [
/*
* Laravel Framework Service Providers...
*/
…….
Anouar\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider::class,<br>
**and**


'aliases' => [
…
'Fpdf' => Anouar\Fpdf\Facades\Fpdf::class,
```

**Controller**

**To export the pdf, add this source code to the Controller :**

```
public function exportpdf() {
 $pdf = new Fpdf();
 $pdf::AddPage();
 $pdf::SetFont('Arial','B',18);
 $pdf::Cell(0,10,"Title",0,"","C");
 $pdf::Ln();
 $pdf::Ln();
 $pdf::SetFont('Arial','B',12);
 $pdf::cell(25,8,"ID",1,"","C");
 $pdf::cell(45,8,"Name",1,"","L");
 $pdf::cell(35,8,"Address",1,"","L");
 $pdf::Ln();
 $pdf::SetFont("Arial","",10);
 $pdf::cell(25,8,"1",1,"","C");
 $pdf::cell(45,8,"John",1,"","L");
 $pdf::cell(35,8,"New York",1,"","L");
 $pdf::Ln();
 $pdf::Output();
 exit;
}
```

**Routing**

**Do not forget to add routing, in file /app/Http/routes.php add this line :**

```
Route::get('exportpdf', 'YourController@exportpdf');
```